# experience poor mental health, difficulty concentrating, remembering or making decisions

Tags: conjunctions

Should the conjunction "and" be inserted between "health" and "difficulty"?

> Underprivileged students are more likely to experience **poor mental health, difficulty** concentrating, remembering or making decisions

Answer (score 1):

There definity should be a "and" somewhere, so either

> Underprivileged students are more likely to experience poor mental health, and difficulty concentrating, remembering or making decisions

Or

> Underprivileged students are more likely to experience poor mental health, difficulty concentrating, and remembering or making decisions

Because of the listing of the at least 2 items here